# What do (CMYK/8*), (CMYK/8)* and (CMYK/8#) mean in Illustrator and Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, cmyk

In Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator, what are the differences between (CMYK/8*), (CMYK/8)* and (CMYK/8#)?
If anyone can explain what these marks (* - #) mean.

Comment: You might need to add a bit more context. Like in what application  you are seeing this in. In many applications a star just simply means unsaved file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An asterisk outside of the color information simply means that the file has unsaved changes. Save the file and the asterisk goes away.

The symbols inside the color information only apply to Photoshop as far as I’m aware...

- **An asterisk (*)** means the color profile associated with the file is not the same as your current working color profile. E.g. your working profile is set to sRGB and you open an image with, or assign to an image, an Adobe RGB profile.
- **A number sign (#)** or pound sign or whatever you want to call it (please don’t call it a “hashtag”), means the file has *no* color profile associated with it (i.e. the image is not color managed).

You can test this in Photoshop by going to *Edit → Assign Profile...* and switching between the options; the symbols will change on the fly with the dialog still open.

I can’t actually find this documented *anywhere* officially – which is absurd. You can read about it here: http://www.earthboundlight.com/phototips/photoshop-pound-sign-asterik-title-bar.html

There are a number of posts about it on the Adobe forums. Noel’s comment from this thread seems apt...
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1065367

> It was designed in the days when computers were supposed to be geeky and cryptic, and Adobe is pretty much allergic to going back and changing old things.

Comment: +1 for admonishing people not to call # a hashtag. I actually saw a quiz show on tv recently where the question was what the symbol is called and the ‘correct’ answer was _hashtag_. Ridonkulous.